# How can I shorten a String join in Java?

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

Could the following code be rewritten in a shorter form (perhaps one statement?) Such as 
`ab = something.join(a,b,"-");` This can be achieved by a Java extension, a dynamic language etc.

```
                String a=....
                String b=.....
                String ab = "";
                if(a!=null && a.length()>0) {
                        ab = a;
                }
                if(b!=null && b.length()>0) {
                        if(ab.length()>0) {
                            ab =ab + "-" + b;
                        } else {
                            ab = b;
                        }
                }
```

Update:

Is there any build-in approach? I don't want to write a method or complicated sentences.

Comment: There's the [`StringBuilder.append()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence)) if that's what you mean by join here.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try [Guava Joiner](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained)

Comment: I'm pretty sure bringing in an external library to merge 2 strings is overkill, especially for this trivial case when system libraries provide all of the functionality.

Comment: @Wug: To do this in one line, you'll end up with something like in SiB's answer; it doesn't really seem that the SDK provides all the functionality for this.

Comment: @Wug I agree that it is overkill. But the Guava library does provide a lot of well written useful utilities and it encourages good design as well. People can benefit a lot from there.

Answer (score 2):

It might be overkill to bring in external libraries for only this functionality, but look at [Apache Commons StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.util.Collection,%20char%29). But you can create a utility method such as:

```
private static String join(String delimiter, String...parts) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String part: parts) {
        if (!isEmpty(part)) {
            if (builder.length() > 0) {
                builder.append(delimiter);
            }
            builder.append(part);
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

private static boolean isEmpty(String part) {
    return part != null && part.length() > 0;   
}
```

I put the delimiter first to allow for variable number of arguments, such as *join("-", null, "b", null, "d", "e", null)*.

Answer (score 1):

```
String ab = (a != null && !a.isEmpty() ? a : "")
          + (a != null && b != null && !a.isEmpty() && !b.isEmpty() ? "-" : "")
          + (b != null && !b.isEmpty() ? b : "");
```

I'm pretty sure that if a string is null and you don't explicitly check for it, the output will be the same as if the string contained the string `"null"`.

Also, using + to append Strings is generally equivalent to using a StringBuilder, but less verbose.  You can verify this by writing a simple example, compiling it to a class file, and decompiling it (most decompilers will not bother replacing StringBuilders with + syntax)

Comment: That's not what he wants, apparently. He wants a (or b) to not show at all and also the separator to be missing when at least one of them is null.

Comment: You may need to omit the  "-" from being appended if a is null, so move it in to the first ternary `(a !=null && a.length()>0) ? a+"-": ""`

Comment: this one generated "-" in the final string even if one of them is null; which is not the requirement.

Comment: Why dont you simply answer `String ab = ((a != null && a.length()>0) ? a+"-" : "") + (b != null ? b : "");`

Comment: @prajeeshkumar what if b is null and a isnt

Comment: Oh yeah, :-) and what if the length is zero like "" ?

Comment: @prajeeshkumar I just fixed that too.  I was hoping something like C#'s isNullOrEmpty existed but it doesnt look like it.  Java is so verbose and yucky.

Comment: What about this ? `String ab = (a != null && a.length()>0)  ?  a+((b!=null && b.length()>0) ? "-"+b : "" ) : (b!=null && b.length()>0)? b : "");` . Same thing with less ifs

Comment: @prajeeshkumar: potato potahto

Answer (score 1):

Just my 2 cents on this:

```
public boolean isEmpty(String string) {
    return string != null && !"".equals(string);
}

public String join(String a, String b, String separator) {
    if (!isEmpty(a) && !isEmpty(b)) {
        return a + separator + b;
    }
    if (!isEmpty(a)) {
        return a;
    }
    if (!isEmpty(b)) {
        return b;
    }
    return "";
}

public String joinLessObvious(String a, String b, String separator) {
    return !isEmpty(a) && !isEmpty(b) ? a + separator + b : !isEmpty(a) ? a : !isEmpty(b) ? b : "";
}
```

Comment: why not make the separator the first argument and use varargs to allow as many strings as you want, like every other language? (PHP, Python, C#, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `StringBuilder` for this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
builder.append((a != null ? a : ""))
       .append(((a != null && b != null) ? "-" : ""))
       .append((b != null ? b : ""));
```

You can create a method to use it in a single line as:

```
public String join(String a, String b, String separator) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
    builder.append((a != null ? a : ""))
           .append(((a != null && b != null) ? "-" : ""))
           .append((b != null ? b : ""));
    return builder.toString();
}
```

and then call it like:

```
System.out.println(join("Another", "Test", "-"));
```

Comment: There is no difference between this and using the + operator to append strings.  If your function consisted of `return (a != null ? a : "") + ((a != null || b != null) ? "-" : "") + (b != null ? b : "")`, You'd end up with `return new StringBuilder.append(a != null ? a : "").append((a != null || b != null) ? "-" : "").append(b != null ? b : "").toString()`.  Also, that OR should be an AND.

Answer (score 0):

This is less code:

```
String ta = (a == null ? "" : a);
String tb = (b == null ? "" : b);
ab = (ta.length() > 0 && tb.length() > 0) ? (ta + "-" + tb) : (ta + tb);
```

... but I wouldn't necessarily call it an improvement.